# How to add multiple arguments to lambda in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, ssms, razor-pages

I am currently working on a library management project. It has 3 tables, TblUser,TblBook and TBlBookStatus. When a user reserves a book, the userID from TblUser,bookID from TblBook is stored in another table(TblBookStatus). I am joining and creating a new list on my database tables on c3. They are stored as lists in my C# code. The code below creates a list that it displays the reserved books.

Note: I did not connect bookID and userID as foreign key on TblBookStatus due to some project specific reasons

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LibMan.Models.DB;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LibMan.Pages
{
    public class LibraryModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly LibMan.Models.DB.LibManContext _context;
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public LibraryModel(LibMan.Models.DB.LibManContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            DisplayBook = new List<TblBook>();
;        }
        public IList<TblBookStatus> TblBookStatus { get; set; }
        public IList<TblBook> TblBook { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<TblBook> DisplayBook { get; set; }
        public IList<TblUser> TblUser{ get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            TblBookStatus = await _context.TblBookStatus.ToListAsync();
            TblBook = await _context.TblBook.ToListAsync();
            TblUser = await _context.TblUser.ToListAsync();

            if (TblBookStatus != null && TblBook != null){
                DisplayBook = TblBook.Where(t => TblBookStatus.Any(ts => ts.BookId == t.BookId));            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the line  `DisplayBook = TblBook.Where(t => TblBookStatus.Any(ts => ts.BookId == t.BookId));` I display the reserved book via bookid, but not by user. 
I want to display the reserved books of currently logged in user, not all users reserved books. So is there any possible way that I can implement this on the lambda statement above? I am imagining something like this, but my syntax is wrong.

```cs
DisplayBook = TblBook.Where(t => TblBookStatus.Any(ts => ts.BookId == t.BookId),a=> TblUser.Any(as=> as.UserId == a.UserId);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**{ EDIT - Answer was marked as correct since behavior was provided but didn't technically answer the question }**

To answer the question: "How to add multiple arguments to lambda in C#", it is important to understand that in this case, the lambda expression is being converted to the delegate type, defined as a parameter to the linq methods such as `Where()` and `Any()`. The lamda must therefore match the "signature" of the delegate type which defines its parameters and return value. In most cases, linq methods expect a delegate called a `Predicate`, defined as `delegate bool Predicate<in T>(T obj)`. The converted lambda must therefore, receive **one** parameter of type `T`, being the `Enumerable` element type, and return a single boolean.

In summary, you cannot add arguments to lambda expression that are to be converted to delegates, it is the delegate type that determines the parameters and return type. A "multiple argument" lambda may look like this, conforming to the signature of the delegate `divide`, two `int` in, one `double` out:

```
Func<int, int, double> divide = (x, y) => { return x / y; };
```

To provide the behavior you requested, an alternative approach you may like to consider:

(I don't have your models to test, so consider this pseudo, but looking at your query, you could try something like...)

```
var DisplayBook =  (from book in TblBook
                    from bookStatus in TblBookStatus
                    from user in TblUser
                    where (book.BookId == bookStatus.BookId) && (user.UserId == currentReader) && (user.UserId == bookStatus.ReservedBy)
                    select book).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Can you suggest a way that I can fetch the userID from the session into currentReader?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't from what you've provided here. Perhaps ask another question with details about how you currently login users :)

Comment: Hi, I actually found a way and tried this, but nothing gets displayed on the page. Can you help me with this if I provide more information?

Comment: I used `var UserEmail = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Email");` to get the currently logged in users email, and I am sure that it doesn't return as null, I printed it out on the console, but when I use the solution you provided above, I don't get anything displayed on the page.

Comment: Solved! I deleted the var decleration in front of DisplayBook, cause I already declared and initialized it before, it was acting as local variable. This is not what the title asks for but I am marking this as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Fuzzy, Glad you are up and running. I have edited my "answer" actually answer your question since you marked it as solve. This way it might prove useful to others also.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply join the datasets by UserId?

```
DisplayBook = (from book in TblBook
               join stat in TblBookStatus
               on book.BookId equals stat.BookId
               join usr in TblUser
               on stat.UserId equals usr.UserId
               where usr.UserId = <currentUserId>
               Select book).ToList();
```

Comment: When I pasted this on my code, I get an error that says : **A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause.
** How can I fix this?I am really new to this stuff, so thanks for helping.

Comment: This also needs some further work to filter by the `CurrentUser`.

Comment: changed `where usr.UserId = <currentUserId>` to `where usr.UserId == <currentUserId>` and this worked too, thanks for helping!

Comment: @Kedar @Fuzzyy I like this answer since it uses `join`. This is more of the standard, correct approach to handling table structures.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
//assumuning current userid is in below variable.
int CurrentUserId;// Fetch it from Session object if you store userid on login

DisplayBook = TblBook.Where(t => TblBookStatus.Any(ts => ts.BookId == t.BookId)
              && TblUser.Any(tb=>tb.UserId==CurrentUserId && tb.BookId==t.BookId));
```

Comment: I think perhaps the very last expression may be incorrect since the elements of TblUser will not have a `BookId` property if I have understood correctly? Should be `&& tb.UserId == ts.ReservedBy`?@AjayKelkar

Comment: `TblBook` joins to `TblBookStatus` on `BookId`, joins to `UserTbl` on `UserId`

Comment: You are right @GeorgeKerwood, I don't have BookId on TblUser.